# How to get the value of a middle variable in a function that need to use 'fsolve'?

Tags: python, function, scipy, scipy-optimize

My first py file is the function that I want to find the roots, like this:

```
def myfun(unknowns,a,b):
    x = unknowns[0]
    y = unknowns[1]
    eq1 = a*y+b
    eq2 = x**b
    z = x*y + y/x
    return eq1, eq2
```

And my second one is to find the value of x and y from a starting point, given the parameter value of a and b:

```
a = 3
b = 2
x0 = 1
y0 = 1
x, y = scipy.optimize.fsolve(myfun, (x0,y0), args= (a,b))
```

My question is: I actually need the value of `z` after plugging in the result of found `x` and `y`, and I don't want to repeat again `z = x*y + y/x + ...`, which in my real case it's a middle step variable without an explicit expression.
However, I cannot replace the last line of fun with `return eq1, eq2, z`, since fslove only find the roots of eq1 and eq2.
The only solution now is to rewrite this function and let it return `z`, and plug in `x` and `y` to get `z`.

Is there a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's the wrong approach.  Since you have `z` as a direct function of `x` and `y`, then what you need is to retrieve those two values.  In the listed case, it's easy enough: given `b` you can derive `x` as the inverse of `eqn2`; also given `a`, you can invert `eqn1` to get `y`.

For clarity, I'm changing the names of your return variables:

```
ret1, ret2 = scipy.optimize.fsolve(myfun, (x0,y0), args= (a,b))
```

Now, invert the two functions:

```
# eq2 = x**b
x = ret2**(1/b)

# eq1 = a*y+b
y = (ret1 - b) / a
```

... and finally ...

```
z = x*y + y/x
```

Note that you should remove the `z` computation from your function, as it serves no purpose.